# How to remove orphaned accounts on folder permission Programmatically whith c#

Tags: c#, file-security

I have a little program that removing account permissions from shared folders. But on some folder's security tab there accounts like this "S-1-5-21-2008445439-890656017-1691616715-1589748".
I have the permission to login that server and remove manually but whit my code I couldn't do because of this error below. How can I remove these accounts. Thanks.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var security = Directory.GetAccessControl(txtBoxPath.Text);
        var rules = security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));

        foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in rules)
        {
                if (rule.IdentityReference.Value == listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text)
                {
                    string name = rule.IdentityReference.Value;
                    RemoveFileSecurity(txtBoxPath.Text, name,
                    FileSystemRights.FullControl |
                    FileSystemRights.Modify |
                    FileSystemRights.Read |
                    FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute |
                    FileSystemRights.ReadPermissions |
                    FileSystemRights.Synchronize |
                    FileSystemRights.ListDirectory |
                    FileSystemRights.ChangePermissions |
                    FileSystemRights.Delete,
                    AccessControlType.Allow);
                    MessageBox.Show("OK");
                }
         }
    }

public static void RemoveFileSecurity(string fileName, string account,
        FileSystemRights rights, AccessControlType controlType)
    {
        // Get a FileSecurity object that represents the 
        // current security settings.
        FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);
        // Remove the FileSystemAccessRule from the security settings.
        fSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account,
            rights, controlType));
        // Set the new access settings.
        File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fSecurity);

    }
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Some or all identity references could not be translated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked this code (with .NET 4.0 if that matters): the exception does not occur by IdentityReference.

The reading of the entries in the foreach loop is ok, if a ACE (access control entry) contains a trustee (user or group) which cannot be resolved, it returns a SID (S-1-5-21-20084454....) as Value. This is fine at this point and the best the framework code can do here.

Later you give the account to

```
new FileSystemAccessRule(account, ...
```

At this point, the exception occurs, since `account` will be seen as an account NAME and a name to SID lookup will take place. And since "S-1-5..." is not a valid account name, the constructor throws.

But: why are you using the string as parameter to your `RemoveFileSecurity`method ?

I changed the code a bit:

```
foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in rules)
{
    if (rule.IdentityReference.Value == listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text)
    {
        RemoveFileSecurity(path, rule);
        MessageBox.Show("OK");
    }
}



public static void RemoveFileSecurity(string fileName, FileSystemAccessRule rule)
{
    // Get a FileSecurity object that represents the 
    // current security settings.
    FileSecurity fSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(fileName);

    // Remove the FileSystemAccessRule from the security settings.
    fSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(rule);

    // Set the new access settings.
    File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fSecurity);

}
```

I hope I understood your problem correctly. I assume you really enter the SID in the textbox and want the entry with the SID to be removed.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer, second you understand it correectly. Im getting access permissions of the folder to a listview item like in the security tab inside the properties of the folder. and clicking them to remove this SID. Thats why Im concerning with the System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.